# Why is onDestroyView in a fragment called immediately after navigating with JetPack Navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

Is it normal behaviour that onDestroyView() is called immediately when you navigate to a different fragment?

I call the following method to navigate:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homefragment_to_detailsfragment)
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Or should everything be restored from a ViewModel? For example my last scroll position in a ScrollView..

Comment: I have an UseCase where the next fragment I push has a semitransparent part and that is causing problems since the previous fragment's UI is getting destroyed :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fragments on the back stack have their views destroyed, but the view state is saved and automatically restored when it comes to the top of the stack again (i.e., you hit the system back button).

Only views with an `android:id` have their state saved and restored, so make sure any important views have an id.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I didn't know about views need to have an id to get auto restored.